# XMLElementnot returning data in Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am new to oracle and hence trying to write a query which will return xml from the relational table emp_metadata which has following columns emp_id and emp_name. The following query is returning null.

```
SELECT XMLElement("Emp", 
                   XMLElement("ID", e.emp_id),
                   XMLElement("Name", e.emp_name)) AS "RESULT" 
FROM emp_metadata e;
```

Any help or hint will be really appreciated.

Comment: The query looks fine to me. Are you sure there is data in the table?

Comment: Yes, there is data and that's why I am confused.

Comment: When you say it's returning null, you mean its returning 0 rows, or its returning rows of nulls? What IDE are you using to query?

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL developer version 4.0, the result set is empty not showing any row count

Comment: what do you see if you run this: SELECT e.emp_id, XMLElement("Emp", XMLElement("ID", e.emp_id), XMLElement("Name", e.emp_name)) AS "RESULT" FROM emp_metadata e;  Also, what version of 10g?

Comment: It's shows data in the column (e.emp_id)  and next column (xmlelement) it shows null.

Comment: Version No: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bi 
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Production                           
CORE 10.2.0.5.0 Production

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get it resolved by converting the output using .getClobVal(). Below is the query

```
    SELECT XMLElement("Emp", 
                   XMLElement("ID", e.emp_id),
                   XMLElement("Name", e.emp_name))**.getClobVal()** AS "RESULT" 
     FROM emp_metadata e;
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Why doesn't it work without getClobVal()?